# Python get request is just returning []

Tags: python

I am trying to perform a get request, however the only thing it seems to be outputting are square brackets. I am trying to grab a value which is called the market cap off of this website [www.coinmarketcap.com](http://www.coinmarketcap.com), however I can not get it to work. This is what I have as my code.

```
import requests
import bs4


source = requests.get("https://www.coinmarketcap.com/charts/").text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source,"lxml")
coincap = soup.select(".sc-12ja2s9-0 dzHJPm")

def output(coincap):
    with open("/Users/user/Desktop/coincap.txt",mode="w+") as f:
        f.write(coincap)

print(coincap)
```

Comment: Is the data you want in soup ? It seems an odd select parameter

Answer (score 1):

Your query selector is incorrect. The element you are looking has 2 CSS classes so you need to join both selectors:

```
coincap = soup.select(".sc-12ja2s9-0.dzHJPm")
```

Cheers,
- J